# Mock testing soap interface

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, response

I have a webservice which I'm calling it asynchronously. Which returns a javax.xml.ws.Response object back. Im trying to mock this webservice interfaces to return the same response object. But Im unable to build the response object.

Webservice call:

```
public Response<com.company.SomeResponse> retrieveSomeValuesAsync(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        com.company.SomeRequestTO arg0
    );
```

So Im making a call to this method. Now My point is how to build the return object(Response) which is a javax.xml.ws.Response object. I was trying to do something like this but it doesn't work. It throws a ClassCastException

Mycode:

```
Response<com.company.SomeResponse> someResponse = (Response<com.company.SomeResponse>)new com.company.SomeResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [javax.xml.ws.Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Response.html) is an interface. So in order to mock up it you have to return an implementation of it. Just simply create a class, implement this interface, override it's methods and then in your method create an instance of this class and return it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest spawning a SOAP endpoint using the JaxWsServerFactoryBean class. I've put up an example JUnit Rule implementation [here](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf).